# bzcompress encoding get every possible character

Tags: php, encoding, compression

i'd like to be able to create an array of all possible character of the encoding used in bzcompress() function.

is it possible to gather this in any way ?
I can't find any answer on google

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `bzcompress()` function outputs binary data. There is no restriction on the characters it may contain — any of the characters from `\x00` to `\xff` may appear.

Comment: So im i right to think that there is a range of 255 different character between \x00 to \xff ?

Comment: Almost. There are 256 characters in that range, not 255.